# Prevent GCP billing access to editor

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I am using the default "Editor" role  for a GCP account. I would like to disable the ability for the Editor Role from having access to the all Billing information. I there a way to do this easily?  I have read through the IAM documentation but it is very confusing.

Comment: It's not a good practice to use legacy role (viewer, owner, editor). Prefer the predefined roles for a better granularity.

Answer (score 0):

The role **Editor** is a member of the **Basic roles**. You cannot modify Basic roles as they are managed by Google.

Select one or more **Predefined Roles** and assign that to IAM members.

Another option is to create a **Custom role** with the permissions you require and assign that to IAM members.

[Google Cloud IAM Basic roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic)

[Google Cloud IAM Predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined)

[Google Cloud IAM Custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#custom_roles)